# How to check to see if what went through the hashtable matched anything

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I have a hashtable and I'm trying to make an if statement right now that will check to see if what went through the hashtable matched anything within it.

```
$netVerConv = @{
        'v2.0' = "lib\net20";
        'v3.0' = "lib\net30";
        'v3.5' = "lib\net35";
        'v4.0' = "lib\net40";
        'v4.5' = "lib\net45";
}
$target = $netVerConv.Get_Item($netVerShort)
if () {
}
```

Above is the area of my code I'm working with, the target variable runs $netVerShort through the $netVerConv hashtable using a Get_Item command. The if statement that I've laid the framework for would check to see if netVerShort matched anything within the hashtable and if it didn't it will stop the program, which I know how to do with a simple exit command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option:

```
if (-not ($target = $netVerConv.Get_Item($netVerShort)))
  { 
    Write-Error "Version $netVerShort not found"
    Exit
  }
```

You could also re-factor that as a Switch

```
$target = 
  Switch ($netVerShort)
   {
    'v2.0'   {"lib\net20"}
    'v3.0'   {"lib\net30"}
    'v3.5'   {"lib\net35"}
    'v4.0'   {"lib\net40"}
    'v4.5'   {"lib\net45"}
    Default  {
               Write-Error "Version $netVerShort not found"
               Exit
             }
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

The other suggestions will work in your specific scenario but in general you should use the `ContainsKey()` method to see if a key exists in the hashtable.  For instance the hashtable `value` could be $null or $false in which case, testing via the result of `Get_Item()` or more simply `Item[$netVerShort]`, will return a false negative. So I recommend this approach for testing existence of a key in a hashtable.  It is also more obvious what your intent is:

```
if (!$netVerConv.ContainsKey($netVerShort) {
    ...   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
if( $target -eq $null ) {
    echo "Didn't Match"
    exit
}
```